# Changing Color of a textView in an infinite loop

Tags: android

I am kind of new in android programming so excuse me for asking this question but I needed help.
I want to change color of a textView in an infinite loop I tried this code:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);

    while(true){
        textView.setTextColor(Color.BLUE);
        try{
            Thread.sleep(500);
        }
        catch (InterruptedException e) {
            Log.e("InterruptedException", "Thread interrupted", e);
        }
        textView.setTextColor(Color.RED);
    }
}
```

But the problem is that UI doesn't update itself. I even tried to put my code in onStart() but that didn't help either, may somebody please help me where should I put my code so that UI updates itself in an infinite loop?

Answer (score 3):

Don't you worry about being a beginner it's fine.

I'd recommend you never use while() to manipulate any View until you read about [Processes and Threads](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/processes-and-threads.html), you must understand what is UI Thread.

**In order to solve your problem:**
Use [Animations](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/view-animation.html), click [here](https://www.raywenderlich.com/128105/introduction-android-animations) for a great tutorial on that subject - it will help you not only change colors for Views but also doing anything else you'd want.

**Later in your quest for knowledge:**
You will learn that you can create your own Custom Views by extending *View.class* and *Overriding the onDraw()* method, then everything you ever want to draw/color/manipulate is possible for you, click [here](https://developer.android.com/training/custom-views/index.html) for more information.

Have fun :)

Answer (score 2):

It looks like your current code is blocking the main thread of the application, which will prevent the UI from properly handling user interaction, view updates, etc.

If you want to make a change on a schedule, you might want to look into posting a Runnable on to the view. So, something like this:

```
TextView textView;
Runnable changeTextColorRunnable = new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        textView.setTextColor(calculateTextColor());
        textView.postDelayed(changeTextColorRunnable, 500);
    }
};

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);

    textView.post(changeTextColorRunnable);
}
```